# Export works but is not displaying the data correctly

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

Brand new to C#. I am working on a ASP MVC app. I am exporting data to an XML and all of that works correctly. The problem I am having is I can't figure out how to make the data output correctly. Basically I am grabbing data from a column which is a number for example 12 based on an ID as well as the logged in users ID. 
This example  pulls 3 rows based on the controllerID as well as userID, and the numbers are as follows: 12, 12, 11. In my XML I would like it to display 1 - 35. They way it is now it is 1-12, 1-12, 1-11. The data is correct, However can I take the numbers returned from my list, add them all together and display them as 1-35.
Here is the code:

```
public ActionResult ExportToXML()
{
    var lClist = db.LightControllers.Where(x => x.userID == LoggedInUser.id).OrderBy(x => x.controllerID).ToList();
    Networks n = new Networks();
    n.computer = "computer1";
    foreach(var i in lClist)
    {

        int numU = Convert.ToInt32(i.NumUniverses);
        for (int j = 0; j < numU; j++)

        {
            network netToAdd = new network();
            netToAdd.NetworkType = "E131";
            netToAdd.ComPort = i.ipaddress;
            netToAdd.BaudRate = (j + 1).ToString();
            netToAdd.MaxChannels = "510";

            n.network.Add(netToAdd);
        }
    }

    XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    ns.Add("", "");
    string path = Server.MapPath("~/XMLFiles/");
    string filename = "x_networks.xml";
    string filepath = Path.Combine(path, filename);
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(filepath))
    {
        System.IO.File.Delete(filepath);
    }
    XmlSerializer serial = new XmlSerializer(typeof(viewmodels.Networks));
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filepath);
    serial.Serialize(writer, n, ns);
    writer.Close();

    return File(filepath, "application/xml", filename);
}
```

Here is an example of the current xml output.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Networks computer="xlights">
    <network NetworkType="E131" ComPort="192.168.1.110" BaudRate="1" MaxChannels="510" />
    <network NetworkType="E131" ComPort="192.168.1.110" BaudRate="2" MaxChannels="510" />
    ...
</Networks>
```

Comment: The "Baudrate" starts over at 1 after it gets through it's 12. When it starts with "comport" of a new IP address it starts with 1, I would like it to continue at 13 and so on.

Comment: Your question does not match your data. Where is 1-12 in the xml output?

Comment: Sorry, it cut it off.
it goes in sequence until 12:
<network NetworkType="E131" ComPort="192.168.1.110 BaudRate="12" MaxChannels="510" />

then it starts the next controller:
<network NetworkType="E131" ComPort="192.168.1.111" BaudRate="1" MaxChannels="510" />

but I need it to go to number 13 and not start back over at 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public ActionResult ExportToXML()
{
    var lClist = db.LightControllers.Where(x => x.userID == LoggedInUser.id).OrderBy(x => x.controllerID).ToList();

    int baudIterator = 1;

    Networks n = new Networks();
    n.computer = "computer1";
    foreach(var i in lClist)
    {

        int numU = Convert.ToInt32(i.NumUniverses);
        for (int j = 0; j < numU; j++)

        {
            network netToAdd = new network();
            netToAdd.NetworkType = "E131";
            netToAdd.ComPort = i.ipaddress;
            netToAdd.BaudRate = baudIterator.ToString();
            netToAdd.MaxChannels = "510";

            n.network.Add(netToAdd);
            baudIterator++;
        }
    }

    XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    ns.Add("", "");
    string path = Server.MapPath("~/XMLFiles/");
    string filename = "x_networks.xml";
    string filepath = Path.Combine(path, filename);
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(filepath))
    {
        System.IO.File.Delete(filepath);
    }
    XmlSerializer serial = new XmlSerializer(typeof(viewmodels.Networks));
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filepath);
    serial.Serialize(writer, n, ns);
    writer.Close();

    return File(filepath, "application/xml", filename);
}
```

Comment: Works like a champ! Thank you so much!

Comment: I changed my 3rd value to 12 as well, so all 3 are 12, but it still only outputs to 35. Any suggestions?

Comment: so did you update the numuniverses to be 13? also, does it write 36 rows with last two baudrate as 35 or does it only output 35 rows?

Comment: No I just changed the last numuniverses to be 12, so they all are 12 for a total of 36.  It only outputs 35 rows.